# "¡No todas somos perras!"

Tags: español-neutral

Esta frase me es algo confusa, porque parece que la persona que lo dice se excluye de ser "perra" pero por otro lado puede entenderse como que se está llamando a sí misma como tal.

¿Alguien podría explicarme la frase?

Comment: ¿Dónde la leíste u oíste? El contexto es clave en frases así.

Comment: There is a non empty set G of girls. There is at least one element in G that has not the property "perra"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Efectivamente, así como está, sin más contexto, la persona que lo dice no está implicando sobre sí misma si es o no *perra*. Una alternativa para resolver esa ambigüedad podría venir en una oración siguiente que diera más contexto:

> No todas somos *perras*. Juanita es una gata.

Quien habla podría emitir la frase sin intención de excluirse a sí misma de la generalización.

> No todas somos *perras*. Al menos yo no.

Aquí, la exclusión queda más explícita.

Dado que el juicio positivo de uno mismo es suceptible de error (y hasta puede ser síntoma de alguna [patología sicológica](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcisismo)), en algunos lugares/contextos culturales es mal visto. Una estrategia para evitarlo es usar este tipo de ambigüedades, dejando al interlocutor la libertad de juzgar. Dada la connotación negativa del adjetivo usado (***perra***) y la referencia a una generalización previa (explícita o implícita), tiendo a pensar que esto es efectivamente lo que sucede en el caso citado.

En pocas palabras, *pareciera que quien habla quiso excluirse sin sonar narcisista*, pero no se puede descartar algo distinto.

Answer (score 1):

Yo creo que es claramente una respuesta negativa a una asunción / suposición / acusación (explícita o implícita) de que el colectivo al que pertenece la persona que lo dice "¡Son todas perras!".

Extraído de un chat sobre [los errores más comunes de los hombres y como solucionarlos](http://www.postubo.com/foro/t/amor-y-sexualidad/amor-y-pareja/los-errores-mas-comunes-de-los-hombres-y-como-solucionarlos/):

> leo q muchos hoombres cometen ese “detalle” al escribir…chicos…no todas somos perras…ni hijas de puta…hay de todo en el camino del señor…